# retrieving longtext from database is not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have mysql database with column lecture_subject, lecturer_name and lecture_desc. In which lecture_desc is set as Longtext.

Through add_lecture.php , every data gets inserted in mysql row.

But when i open it in edit_lecture.php, it is showing first two fields properly, but not longtext...

Code in edit_lecture.php is as follows...

```
    Lecture Subject : <input name="lecture_subject" id="lecture_subject" type="text" size="40" value="<?=$lecture_data['lecture_subject']?>" />

    Lecturer Name : <input name="lecturer_name" id="lecturer_name" type="text" size="40" value="<?=$lecture_data['lecturer_name']?>" />

    Lecture Details : <textarea name="lecture_desc" id="lecture_desc" type="textarea" cols="100" rows="40" value="<?=$lecture_data['lecture_desc']?>"></textarea>
```

Here Lecture Details are not shown as value from database.

Comment: Could you show us your table schema and your query?

Comment: table - lecture_id (int 11), lecture_subject (varchar 255), lecturer_name (varchar 255) and lecture_desc (longtext)

Comment: querry - $bsq->connect_db();

$lecture_id=$_GET["lecture_id"];
$where="lecture_id='".$_GET["lecture_id"]."'";
$lecture_dataRS=$bsq->webdreamselect('eo_lecture',$where,'','','','1');
$lecture_data=mysql_fetch_array($lecture_dataRS);

Comment: @drManishJoshi: Please go back and edit the question and paste your table and query in there.  They are very difficult to read in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented under [Controls](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#initial-value):

> In general, a control's "*initial value*" may be specified with the control element's `value` attribute. However, the initial value of a [`TEXTAREA`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#edef-TEXTAREA) element is given by its contents

Therefore:

```
<textarea name="lecture_desc"
          id="lecture_desc"
          cols="100"
          rows="40"
         ><?=htmlentities($lecture_data['lecture_desc'])?></textarea>
```

Comment: can you show me example please ? I am new to php and mysql